# Search B-Tree in O(log(t)*h)

Tags: data-structures, tree

Given a B-tree such that in every node there are at most t keys and n nodes, I know that I can search the tree in O(t*h) where h is the height of the tree.
Is there a way to that in O(log(t)*h)?

Comment: Binary search instead of trying all keys within one node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a binary search to find the key you need within one node.

Or, better, store all keys and links within a node in a binary search tree.